# Replacing rotted brickmold and sill - what’s the sill piece called?

Tags: windows, dry-rot

Thanks for your time.

I’m replacing exterior brickmold and don’t want to spend good money after bad so I could benefit from others’ experience.

Here’s a picture, I’ve circled the piece in question:

[image: rotted exterior sill]

Anyone know what it’s called and what it’s profile is? I couldn’t find anything like it online, or at Menards. It’s driving me batty not knowing what they call this specific kind of sill.

The house is a 1965 colonial, so I assume this is original millwork.

**Update**: another angle to show how far the sill sits out in front of the vertical pieces of brickmold casing:

[image: a side angle of the rotted sill]

Just thought I’d ask this community before I do the obvious next step and tear it out to inspect and measure.

Thanks!

Comment: google `window frame parts` to get this http://www.pella.com/glossary/window-anatomy/

Comment: Thanks, though before posting I’d googled my way to spells already and it doesn’t describe this specific type of sill. I’ll edit my original post to make it clearer what I’m looking at, profile-wise. My goal is to repair and replace what is appropriate/recommended.

Comment: Try threshold in your search

Comment: @Kris it’s a window not a door

Comment: Ha my bad  didn’t read close enough. Sill nose perhaps?

Comment: The circled piece is called the sill. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8iu9dLrV-E this vid shows what is involved in replacing one

Comment: They seem to change  mill work profiles regularly . My house was built in 1996 and I  need to replace the same sill  the local yard does not have the same stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom piece of your wood window is called the sill.

I had to replace some rotted sills in my home an had a piece leftover 
Here are some pictures of it to show the profile. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bear to replace compared to the brickmold! Thanks for posting these photos

Comment: To add to Kris's response and pictures, the rotted portion of your window is of the original window sill. The current window you have is a renovation window that has been seated into the existing frame. That style of renovation can be called a "box insert" whereas the original window was likely a casement with its sash removed and the new window inserted, leaving the og frame and wall intact.

Comment: @AnonyTech how the heck could you identify that I have a renovation window seated into an original frame?